# Crear archivo en el directorio actual

Tags: python, archivo

quiero realizar un programa sencillo que me cree un archivo .txt en el directorio en el que esta mi archivo de Python. Tengo este código que es muy simple pero no me crea el archivo en el directorio en el que se encuentra, sino en C\Users\MiUsuario.

```
from io import open

archivo=open("archivo.txt","w")

frase="prueba"

archivo.write(frase)
```

Answer (score 0):

Deberías revisar lo siguiente:

¿Qué tienes en la variable de entorno `PYTHONPATH`?

¿Desde dónde estás ejecutando el script?

Dicho esto puedes establecer la ruta completa del archivo de destino con:

```
import os

archivo = open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), "archivo.txt"), "w")
```

`os.path.realpath(__file__)` nos devuelve la ruta absoluta del script actual.

`os.path.dirname()` nos da la ruta de la carpeta.

`os.path.join()` une las rutas utilizando el separador del sistema.

Como resultado tendrás la ruta absoluta del archivo de destino.

Answer (score 0):

Lo más fácil en este caso sería poner la ruta absoluta de donde quieres guardar el archivo

```
f = open ('C:\\mi_carpeta\\archivo.csv','w')
```

Esto se usaría para guardar el archivo en una carpeta llamada "mi carpeta", tú deberías poner la ruta donde quieres guardar el archivo y al final el nombre con el que quieres guardar el archivo. Acuérdate de poner doble \ para separar los directorios y archivos, si no te dará error.